# Why did the regular expression of greed——How to support multiline mode？

Tags: yacc, lex

I want to parse multiline comment, but it's always greedy.

The regular expression:

```
MUL_COMMENT ("#*"(.|\n)*?"*#")
```

flex file fragment:

```
<DIRECTIVE>{MUL_COMMENT} {BEGIN INITIAL;
    printf("mul comment for directive end:%s\n",yytext);yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return COMMENT;}
```

The text file:

```
#*erewrewrewr
wer*#

#set( $a=7)

#*#ere
wrewrewrwe*#
```

The parse result:

```
Node:astn=Comment,image:"#*erewrewrewr\nwer*#\n\n#set(            $a=7)\n\n#*#ere\nwrewrewrwe*#"

mul comment for directive end:#*erewrewrewr
wer*#

#set( $a=7)

#*#ere
wrewrewrwe*#
```

The image is his string matching,apparently he was greedy!How to fix it,please help me!

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to not match `*#` inside your comment:

```
MUL_COMMENT    "#*"([*]*[^*#]|[#])*"*#"
```